# What do they mean by signed and unsigned when talking about the intersection of two simple closed curves?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

When it says, " There are two natural ways to count the number of intersection points between two simple closed curves in a surface : signed and unsigned ", what do they mean by signed and unsigned?

Answer (score 1):

"Unsigned" means just count up the number of crossings.

"Signed" means count them with a sign. That is, some crossings count as $+1$ and others as $-1$. Loosely, the determination goes as follows. Let's say the curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ are parameterized. Define a crossing to be positive if when travelling along $C_1$ in the direction of the parameterization, $C_2$ is moving in the direction to the left of $C_1$. If the parameterizations are smooth, then this is equivalent to saying the velocity vectors for $C_1$ and $C_2$ obey the right hand rule at the crossing. Otherwise, the crossing is negative.